# There is any way to redirect an url to localhost:443?

Tags: iptables, squid

There is any way to redirect the address "meuvivo.vivo.com.br" to "localhost:443" using squid or iptables?

The idea is: when the client connects to the squid and tries to connect to meuvivo.com.br it connects to localhost:443

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use `squid` or `iptables` - just use an entry in the `hosts` file.  If you're on Linux, Mac or another *nix system, that's in `/etc/hosts`.  For Windows it's on `C:\Windows\System32\etc\hosts` (if I remember correctly - been a while).

Just add the following entry to the end of the file:

```
127.0.0.1       meuvivo.vivo.com.br
```

After that, `https://meuvivo.vivo.com.br` will automatically connect to `127.0.0.1:443`

Comment: Why the downvote?  True, this doesn't redirect a query, but it solves the nominal case of testing locally.